# (string)reader[0] vs Convert.ToString(reader[0])

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldatareader

what's better

```
var s =  (string)reader[0]
```

or

```
var s = Convert.ToString(reader[0])
```

?

Comment: Why not reader[0].ToString() as an option?

Comment: Can you define "better"? Faster? More robust? Easier to read? Smaller memory footprint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say `reader.GetString(0)`

Comment: Circra release of NETFX 2 I did lots of research and found the Get<T> methods with the indexed looked was the best performing of all reader methodologies.

Comment: I have also measured this in 3.5 and found that this performed measurably better than `(string)reader[0]`.

Comment: Are there issues with reader.GetString(0) reading blob values, e.g. Varchar(Max)?

Answer (score 6):

Why did nobody considered the readability and maintainability?

I know the author asks about:

```
var s =  (string)reader[0]      
or    
var s = Convert.ToString(reader[0])
```

But what about:

```
string s = reader["Fieldname"].ToString();
```

thats more readable and more safe if you exchange/delete/add columns and the index is changing... this is for sure more worth.

One guy said the hard cast is 30% faster. Well 30% of 1 ms are 1,333 ms ? surely not 30% of the whole data fetching.

Comment: This answer should be heeded.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Conveys that you are sure that reader[0] is a string and 
// if it's not you probably have bigger problems 
// than the resulting exception
var s =  (string)reader[0];

// Conveys that you are hoping that reader[0] is convertible to a string
var s = Convert.ToString(reader[0])
```

So it's probably a matter of choosing taking in consideration the context.

Comment: +1 for considering the readability and intent of the code, and not just performance.

Answer (score 3):

If reader[0] is actually a string, then the `(string)reader[0]`.

It's clearer and most probably faster (unless the compiler does some magical optimization I don't know about).

Answer (score 3):

```
var s =  (string)reader[0]
```

will give you a class cast exception if it can't be cast as a string, whereas

```
var s = Convert.ToString(reader[0])
```

will handle it more gracefully and you will get null if it can't be converted.  This will also handle more types of object for reader[0] as the other method will only allow casts where the type can be cast to a string, whereas this will support any type which the Convert Class can handle.  Which I assume is more.  But may not be...

Answer (score 3):

This is faster, about **~30% faster** in my testing:

```
var s =  (string)reader[0];
```

This, however, won't blow up when it's null:

```
var s = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `reader.GetString(0);`?

Answer (score 0):

what about

> reader[0].ToString();

Answer (score -1):

I would go with

```
reader[0].ToString();
```